# Excel 2010 Modify default sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

How can I save changes to the default sheet for the Insert Sheet command?  I get my modifications in Book1, Sheet1 but they do not hold for newly inserted sheets.

Answer (score 3):

Create your sheet template and remove other sheets from your workbook.

Save the workbook:

- File name "Sheet"
- File type "Excel Template (*.xltx)"
- Location "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\XLSTART"

The next time you start Excel, this is used as your default new sheet template.